# Problema com font-face de uma única fonte

Tags: css

Estou tendo problema com uma fonte em um site que estou desenvolvendo.
O nome da fonte é **modern nº 20**, fiz o font-face dela e não está funcionando.
Meu código está correto?

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'modern';
    src: url('../fontes/modern-no-20-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fontes/modern-no-20-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fontes/modern-no-20-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fontes/modern-no-20-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../fontes/modern-no-20-webfont.svg#modern') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

.bannerPTextoL1 {
    font-family: "modern";
    font-size: 300px;
    color: #001f2e;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    width: 1920px;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Aparentemente sim, talvez o problema seja esse valor no `url(...)`. Sua fonte está um diretório acima em uma pasta chamada `fontes` mesmo?

Comment: Está sim. Nesse mesmo diretório eu tenho outras fontes que funcionam normalmente.

Comment: Passa o caminho completo da url para a gente testar

Comment: caminho completo http://www.musicalabertura.com.br/site/fontes/modern-no-20-webfont.eot

Answer (score 1):

Bem, pelo que eu vi a fonte funciona corretamente.

Como ela é(download da fonte feito diretamente da url citada):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e removendo o comentário `<!-- -->` da parte do site onde a `DIV` com a classe `.bannerPTextoL1`  se localiza e aplicando o estilo citado como pode ver na imagem, fica assim (coloquei uma cor branca para facilitar a visualização):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não há diferenças, seu font-face funciona corretamente.
Provavelmente você deve ter baixado uma fonte incorreta pensando que seria a correta.